# Prove that the following element is an invertible element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Question in Abstract Algebra:

How can I prove that: $r+s \sqrt{2}$ , when $r$ and $s$ are rational, is an invertible element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

(In fact I need to prove that's a number field but I only have problem with this.)

Comment: r and s are rational(Q)

Comment: yes , Q(2√) ...

Comment: HINT: (In $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$).$(r+s\sqrt{2})(r-s\sqrt{2})=r^2-2s^2\not=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $r+s\sqrt{2}\ne 0$, then
$$\frac{1}{r+s\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{r+s\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{r-s\sqrt{2}}{r-s\sqrt{2}}=\frac{r}{r^2-2s^2}+\frac{-s}{r^2-2s^2}\sqrt{2}.$$

You will have to verify that $r-s\sqrt{2}\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Multiplying by $r - s\sqrt{2}$ gives

$$(r + s \sqrt{2}) (r - s \sqrt{2}) = r^2 - 2s^2$$

Convince yourself that this quantity is non-zero (provided that $r$ and $s$ aren't both zero), and use that fact to find an inverse for $r + s\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $r$ and $s$ are both nonzero rationals, then $r^2-2s^2 \neq 0$. Clearly,

$$(r+s \sqrt{2})\frac{r-s \sqrt{2}}{r^2-2s^2}=1,$$
so we have found an inverse of $r+s \sqrt{2}\neq0$, namely
$$ \frac{r}{r^2 -2s^2} + \frac{-s}{r^2-2s^2}\sqrt{2}.$$